# FileNotFoundException with JSP but Java code works

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to use jsp and java to display information read from a csv to a website. I'm using Tomcat v9.0 with Eclipse.

The java code works as expected when running it just in java—it reads the csv data into an ArrayList of Song objects. However, when running the jsp file, it throws a filenotfoundexception.

The original java code reads and parses the csv in the getter function of "ReadBillboardCSV" here:

```
public ArrayList<BillboardSong> getReadBillboardCSV() throws FileNotFoundException {
    Reader in = new FileReader("testFile.csv");
    ArrayList<BillboardSong> readSongs = new ArrayList<BillboardSong>();
    try {
        Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.RFC4180.parse(in);
        for (CSVRecord record : records) {
                BillboardSong newSong = new BillboardSong();
                readSongs.add(newSong);
                newSong.setPosition(Integer.parseInt(record.get(0)));
```

My servlet calls the getter, then sets the attribute.

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession ses = request.getSession(true);
    ReadBillboardCSV readData = new ReadBillboardCSV();
    ArrayList<BillboardSong> songsArray = readData.getReadBillboardCSV();
    ses.setAttribute("billboardArray", songsArray);
    }
```

Here is the main portion of the jsp:

```
<%
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/ServletOne");
    rd.forward(request, response);
%>
```

Is there a reason it cannot read the file when I run it on Tomcat?

Comment: Where is your file?

Comment: Check what the working directory is and make sure that the file exists there, eg log new File("").getAbsolutePath()

Comment: my file is in the main project folder. I made a copy and put it in the directory folder as well, but it still gives me the same error. Should I be using an absolute path when I read it in with reader?

Comment: No. You should be reading it as a resource using something like the servlet context.

Comment: @nitind Can I do this while preserving the getter method in the java code? Or can I move it to the servlet

Comment: _"Is there a reason it cannot read the file when I run it on Tomcat?"_ The Exception says you don't find the file, not that you cannot read it (AccessDeniedException for example)

Comment: `FileReader("testFile.csv")` is opening a relative path (which is certainly relative to the Tomcat's install dir), while you probably want a more deterministic way to find your file such as `FileReader("/home/user/.../testFile.csv")`